# connect localhost in ngsi source operator

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I try to retrieve data from orion broker in Wirecloud via NGSI Source Operator. I run orion broker in a VM-Centos. When i give to the operator my local host "http://127.0.0.1:1026/v2/entities" or localhost:1026 and the default ngsi proxy ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org i take the error "Error creating subscription in the context broker server: Connection Error' .
If i put the ip in a browser, i get my json results. Should i subscribe something in orion broker?
Thanks.

Comment: Same question here, please.